# Please help me with this visualisation exercise

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I'm learning parallel transport and I was given a visualization exercise to help me understand it. The instructions are as follows:

> Stand up and hold your right arm by your side, the palm of your hand
>   pointing to your left. Consider your shoulder to be the center of a
>   sphere, so when you move your arm without bending it, your hand will
>   live on the surface of the sphere. Without twisting your arm, swing
>   your arm out to the side until it is horizontal. Your palm is now
>   pointing down. Keeping your arm horizontal, swing your arm until it is
>   pointing directly in front of you. Your palm is still pointing down.
>   Now swing your arm down to its starting location by your side. Your
>   palm is now pointing directly behind you, having been rotated by 90
>   degrees from when you began. Your hand's 2-D space is curved.

I'm stuck at

> ... Without twisting your arm, swing your arm out to the side until it is
>   horizontal ...

Here's what I've done:
[image]

How do I swing my arm till it is horizontal? Am I doing it right? How would you implement this yourself?

Comment: "Stand up and hold your right arm by your side": that is, down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The first stage is like 2:46-2:48 (also repeated around 6:10) in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmFAmTNxSuM).

Comment: You have a very unique mind. Thank you!